# Trouble building V8 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-7, v8, gyp

I have a need to build a desktop app using embedded V8. The online documentation says I need to use gyp. OK, but I can't seems to download gyp. Keep getting an "unable to connect to repository at URL" message. Is there another way to build V8? Is there another URL besides the one published by Google that I can use?

TIA

Comment: No idea what gyp is. Last time I built V8 on windows I did not need such a thing... I think.

Comment: Well can you share what you did? How recently? GYP - Generate Your Projects

Comment: Unfortunately it was around late last year and I had a disk crash since. So I cannot really verify.